# ios repeat/reverse animation is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is code i am using. But its not working (execute only once). What i am doing wrong?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                NSLog(@"animating...");
                laserView.frame = CGRectMake(0, scannerOverlayView.frame.size.height, scannerOverlayView.frame.size.width, 3);
            } completion:^(BOOL done){
            }];
```

Comment: Are you using `laserView` from nib? with autolayout? I tried with programatically uiview and its working fine.

Comment: Nopes, i am creating `laserView` programatically.

Comment: i am adding `laserView` in an overlay view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the first frame in completion block.

```
completion:^(BOOL done){
laserView.frame = initial frame  
            }];
```

Comment: i have tried that but still not working. It just execute only once.
`completion:^(BOOL done){
laserView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scannerOverlayView.frame.size.width, 3);
            }];`